# Using Newton's method to find an optimized matrix

Tags: statistics, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, statistical-inference

I'm trying to apply Newton's method to find a local optimum of the matrix $\Sigma$ to minimize the objective function:

$f(\Sigma) = -\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(-\ln{2\pi} - \frac{1}{2}\ln{|\Sigma|}-\frac{1}{2}\omega_n^T\Sigma\omega_n\right) - \left(\frac{\nu}{2}|\Phi|
- \nu\ln{2} -\ln{\Gamma_2{(\frac{\nu}{2})}} -\frac{\nu+3}{2}\ln{|\Sigma|} - \frac{1}{2}tr{(\Phi\Sigma^{-1})}\right)$

Assume only $\Sigma$ is the variable in the equation. Newton's method approaches the local optimum by iterating this:

$x_{n+1} = x_n - [Hf(x_n)]^{-1}\nabla f(x_n)$

I'm confused on how to apply Newton's method to solve this problem. 
Because my variable is a matrix, the first-order derivative and second-order derivative are both matrices. Although it seems like the process will go through, I still feel something's wrong.

Please give me some suggestions on solving this, thanks!

Comment: Think of $\Sigma$ as a vector rather than a matrix.  For example, if $\Sigma$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $Hf$ will be an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your replay! In this case I will take the gradient to be an $n^2 \times 1$ vector? Kinda confused with the mapping. Is there a conventional way to do a matrix into a vector, or any example that I can find online?

Comment: I don't think there is any convention.  I would probably use a lexigraphic order, i.e. look at the entries of $\Sigma$ as all the rows placed in one large row.